# refresh gui in swt button listener

Tags: java, button, swt, redraw, styledtext

I have following class.

1. Why the `btnDecorate` is allways enabled? I wanted to disable the button when the loop is under processing.
2. Why `text.redraw()` works only in the end of loop? I wanted to see the box sequently on every character.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class SampleRefreshStyledText {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    final Button btnDecorate = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnDecorate.setText("Decorate");

    final StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.NONE);
    text.setText("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRQ\n1234567890");

    btnDecorate.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            btnDecorate.setEnabled(false);

            for (int i = 0; i < text.getText().length(); i++) {
                StyleRange styleRange = new StyleRange();
                styleRange.start = i;
                styleRange.length = 1;
                styleRange.borderColor = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
                styleRange.borderStyle = SWT.BORDER_SOLID;
                styleRange.background = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY);

                text.setStyleRange(null);
                text.setStyleRange(styleRange);
                text.redraw();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            btnDecorate.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {}           
    });        

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write loops like this with SWT.

All UI operations occur on the single UI thread. Calling `Thread.sleep` puts the UI thread to sleep and nothing at all will happen.

The `redraw` call only requests that the text is redrawn, it will not actually happen until the next time the `display.readAndDispatch()` is run, so doing this repeatedly in a loop doesn't work.

What you have to do is run the first step of your loop once. You must then arrange to run the next step 500ms later **without blocking the thread**. You can do this using the `Display.timerExec` method to request that code is run at a later time:

```
display.timerExec(500, runnable);
```

where `runnable` is a class implementing `Runnable` that does the next step. At the end of this code you call `timerExec` again until you have worked your way through all the steps.